# Как реализовать таймер/напоминание и взаимодействие с датой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как реализовать таймер/напоминание по секундам, минутам, часам и дням включительно?

Пример:

```
"Установите таймер":
Дни : Часы : Минуты : Секунды
"Дедлайн": Дата, Часы : Минуты
```

Как получить автоматический отчёт времени при/после указания даты?

Пример:

```
"До выбранной Вами даты (и времени) осталось":
Дни : Часы : Минуты : Секунды
```

---

Меня не столь интересует код, который бы был весьма кстати, сколько интересен сам способ реализации таймера и, к примеру, привязки к дате со временем.

Comment: Вы попросили закрыть вопрос. Уточните, зачем это делать? Вроде бы уже и ответ дан.

Comment: Чтобы ещё не комментировали и не беспокоили мою душу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html

```
>>> import datetime
>>> deadline = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 9, 30)
>>> print(deadline)
2016-02-11 09:30:00
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(deadline - now)
0:23:29.521400
```

Comment: > 0:23:29.521400 - это только время? Там плавающая точка? Как убрать? Дни вывести через множество различных "а, если"?

Comment: Там будут и дни, если deadline подальше поставить, например: `4 days, 0:23:29.521400`. Печатается строка а вообще `deadline - now` это объект `datetime.timedelta`, там из него все что нужно можно вытащить. Читайте ссылку. Можно найти на русском, погуглив python datetime.

Comment: Да-да, спасибо. Если бы не мой Elementary уровень, то мог бы и обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

В бесконечном цикле каждую секунду проверяем время:

```
import datetime
import time

deadline = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 15, 46, 20)
print('Deadline time: {}.'.format(deadline.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')))

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('Current time: {}.    '.format(now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')), end='\r')

    if now >= deadline:
        print('Deadline!')
        break

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь;)